# Spring boot Websocket without SockJS

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, rxjs, spring-websocket, sockjs

I have been struggling with this for at least two weeks now. I'm pretty new to websockets. I have good experience with rest endpoints.

My use case is simple. Client initiates a websocket connection sending some info to server, and server uses that info and, sends client some info back at some regular interval say every 5 seconds.
I followed the tutorial here - https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/
It works perfectly as explained.
As per the above tutorial, client initiates a http request, which gets upgraded to websocket.

In my case front end is an angular 10 application, and the front end developer prefers to use `rxjs/websocket` and doesn't want to use `SockJS client`, as he is sure we don't have to support any legacy browsers, and this is where I'm struck.
Apparently `rxjs/websocket` needs url in `ws://` protocol.

From the following snippet, I thought my equivalent ws protocol would be
`ws://localhost:8080/test` However, it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure what is wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config)
    {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws/");
    

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addEndpoint("/test");
    }

}
```

From the tutorial, I changed `app.js`, as follows to test this out.

```js
function connect() {
    // var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/test'); This works perfectly
    // stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/test');
    stompClient = Stomp.client(ws);

    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/' + $("#site").val(), function (message) {
            showMessageSentFromServer(JSON.stringify(message.body));
        });
    });
}
```

When I open up the developer tool of chrome and inspect, I see the websocket connection has be established and upgraded or that is what I see. However, in the console, I see an error log as follows. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Screen shot of network:

[image]

Console failure log:

```
stomp.min.js:8 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL '[object WebSocket]' is invalid.
    at Object.client (http://localhost:8080/webjars/stomp-websocket/stomp.min.js:8:7229)
    at connect (http://localhost:8080/app.js:18:25)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:54:9)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (http://localhost:8080/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js:3:10315)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (http://localhost:8080/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js:3:8342)
```

Now long story short, I managed to disable SockJs on the server side, by removing `withSockJS()`. So what is my equivalent `ws` protocol URL?

Also, another challenge I have apart from this is, how do I set up a scheduled process that can send messages to a websocket topic that the client has subscribed, based on the input from the client. I know it is easy to set up a scheduled process using a `@Scheduled` annotation. But in my case, I wanted some inputs from the client which is required inside the scheduled process.

Also, please share any resources or examples that you have that explains how to implement a websocket stomp client subscription to a topic using `rxjs`

Comment: From the [stomp docs](https://stomp-js.github.io/stomp-websocket/codo/extra/docs-src/Usage.md.html): `var url = "ws://localhost:15674/ws";
  var client = Stomp.client(url);` - you should pass just url string instead of already created websocket object.

Comment: The code posted does not seem to use [Rxjs websocket](https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/webSocket) as it should start with lowercase like  `ws = new webSocket('ws://localhost:8080/test')`

Comment: @arturgrzesiak you are my saviour! That seem to fix my issue. I just realised how silly was that mistake, but worth a million. Thank you so much!

Comment: @arturgrzesiak I'm happy to award my bounty to you, if you can post your comment as an answer within next 3 hours, as I can't award for replies. Thanks again.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by making two simple changes.

1. I enabled my backend to support both `ws` and `http` protocols by adding two endpoints to the `WebSocketConfig` as shown below - one with and the other one without `sockjs` as shown below, which made my backend more flexible in terms of supporting both the protocols to establish `websocket` connection. I don't know why this wasn't mentioned anywhere in spring docs or else. Perhaps, people thought it is implied!

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{

        @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config)
        {
                config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
                config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws/");
        }

        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry)
        {
                registry.addEndpoint("/test"); // This will allow you to use ws://localhost:8080/test to establish websocket connection
                registry.addEndpoint("/test").withSockJS(); // This will allow you to use http://localhost:8080/test to establish websocket connection
        }

}
```

2. As pointed out by `@arturgrzesiak` in previous comment, there was an error in the parameter passed to the `Stomp.client(url)` I was silly and passing `ws`object instead of plain `url`.

```
stompClient = Stomp.client('ws://localhost:8080/test');
```

Finally,

If someone wants to use `SockJS` client to connect, they can connect using

```
var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/test');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
```

If someone wants to use just a plain `Websocket` object to connect, use the following.

```
stompClient = Stomp.client('ws://localhost:8080/test');
```

I posted this solution as this will be useful to someone out there who had a similar painful experience, and they might find it useful.

Comment: Yes, very useful indeed, cheers!. Only thing I'll add is to register the endpoint including allowed origin(s) (SB v2.5.4), e.g. `registry.addEndpoint("/test").setAllowedOrigins("*");`

Comment: This fixed my issue, thanks. I thought I could create a websocket manually and pass it via .over but .client(url) worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the comment:

> From the stomp docs: var url = "ws://localhost:15674/ws";   var client = Stomp.client(url); - you should pass just url string instead of already created websocket object.

Answer (score -1):

Im no expert but I though all WebSocket URIs used the scheme ws: or wss: for a secure WebSocket. To get more familiar with WebSockets you should take a look at [How Do Websockets Work?](https://sookocheff.com/post/networking/how-do-websockets-work/).

When I was starting out with Websockets I learned a lot form [Androidhive; Building Group Chat App using Sockets](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/)

Im not so used to spring Websockets but in the old days when I was using Java EE it was relatively simple. All you had to do was configure a server endpoint with the annotated @ServerEndpoint. Form there you would use the functions with annotation

```
@OnMessage
public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {
    ...
}

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {
    ...
    // Here you can start a session handler
    // which will send message every 5 sec or so.
    s = new SessionHandler(session, id);
    s.start();
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(Session session) {
    ...
}
```

Here is how you would send messages

```
public void send(String msg) throws IOException {
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg);
    // session.getBasicRemote().flushBatch(); 
}
```

And here is the javascript side,

```
var wsUri = "ws://" + (document.location.hostname === "" ? "localhost" : document.location.hostname) + ":" +
            (document.location.port === "" ? "80" : document.location.port);

var websocket;
function connect() {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

    websocket.onopen = function (evt) {
        onOpen(evt);
    };
    websocket.onmessage = function (evt) {
        onMessage(evt);
    };
    websocket.onerror = function (evt) {
        onError(evt);
    };

    websocket.onclose = function (evt) {
        onClose(evt);
    };
}

connect();
```

I know this is focused on Java EE but maybe you can consider using Java EE, its not so bad anymore. Take a look at this more in depth sample if you are interested [How to build applications with the WebSocket API for Java EE and Jakarta EE](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/how-to-build-applications-with-the-websocket-api-for-java-ee-and-jakarta-ee)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I was looking for.